# Jquery change the class of a whole li

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code in my JSP:

```
 <div class="thedescription">
     <ul class="descriptionlanguages">
        <li id="EN_langLinkLi" class="selectedlanguage" >
               <a id="EN_langLink" class="showDifferentLang" href="#">EN</a>
        </li>
        <li id="IT_langLinkLi" class="notSelectedlanguage" >
            <a id="IT_langLink" class="showDifferentLang" href="#">IT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

and the script, that I use to change the class of the whole li

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
                $('li').click(function() {
                      alert ('lsls');
                      $('#thedescription ul li ').each(function(){
                       this.className = 'notSelectedlanguage';
                });
              });
         });
        </script>
```

but does not change anything  !

Comment: Put your js in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ })`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addClass()` to add class to clicked `li` and `removeClass()` to remove this class from siblings `li`

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('notSelectedlanguage').siblings().removeClass('notSelectedlanguage');
});
```

```css
.notSelectedlanguage {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thedescription">
  <ul class="descriptionlanguages">
    <li id="EN_langLinkLi" class="selectedlanguage">
      <a id="EN_langLink" class="showDifferentLang" href="#">EN</a>
    </li>
    <li id="IT_langLinkLi" class="notSelectedlanguage">
      <a id="IT_langLink" class="showDifferentLang" href="#">IT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.className = 'notSelectedlanguage;`, you could try `$(this).addClass("notSelectedlanguage");`